# How can I find all bugs that have been fixed in an Eclipse release?

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla

Specifically, how can I get a list of all bugs that were fixed in EGit Kelper SR2 (4.3.2)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try going to Eclipse Bugzilla [Advanced Search](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=advanced).

Select EGit in the Product list, and FIXED in the Resolution list. Expand the Detailed Bug Information section and select the EGit version (I think this is 3.2.0 for EGit). This gives me a list of 27 fixes.

Comment: For reference: This bug says "[EGit 3.2 ships with Kepler SR](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416720#c4)" and [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/3.2#Bug_Fixes) contains a [link to 55 bugs and 13 enhancements](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?list_id=3805932&resolution=FIXED&resolution=DUPLICATE&classification=Technology&chfieldto=2013-12-18&chfield=resolution&query_format=advanced&chfieldfrom=2013-10-03&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&product=EGit).

Comment: Maybe your approach only lists bugs that were *found* in 3.2? :-/

Comment: Using `Target Milestone` rather than `Version` lists 59 bugs